# I am getting heap buffer overflow error in C programming

Tags: c

I was trying to solve leetcode where I need to find best max value and min value then simply substract but I am getting address sanitizer heap buffer overflow error.When I try to get only max or min value program works fine but whenever I try to get both value bug occurs

```
int maxProfit(int* prices, int pricesSize){

    int max = 0;
    int min = 2000000000;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int minIndex = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < pricesSize; i++){
        if(prices[i+1] == NULL )
            break;

            if(min < prices[i])
                break;

         else if(prices[i] < prices[i+1]  ){
            min = prices[i];
            minIndex = i;
         }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < pricesSize; i++){
        if(prices[i+1] == NULL )
            break;

            if(max > prices[i])
                break;

         else if(prices[i] < prices[i+1]  ){
            max = prices[i];
            maxIndex = i;
         }
    }
    int result=0;
    
    result = max - min;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You're not checking if `i + 1` goes outside the length of the array before accessing.

Comment: prices[i+1] is problem for last iteration

Comment: `prices[i+1] == NULL` doesn't make sense. You pass `int *prices` as a parameter. the `[..]` acts as a dereference, so `prices[i+1]` will have type `int`. Further, you iterate to `pricesSize`. When `i == pricesSize - 1` access of `prices[i+1]` will access one-past the end of your array (or block of memory) giving buffer overflow.

Comment: What is the function supposed to do? Show your test code that calls `maxProfit`. [Edit] your question.

Comment: Anyway I guess `for(int i = 0; i < pricesSize; i++)` -> `for(int i = 0; i < pricesSize - 1; i++)` and removing both `if(prices[i+1] == NULL ) break;` alltogether should solve your problem.